# Is it possible to install MATE 1.26 on Ubuntu MATE?

Tags: 20.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, 21.04

While visiting repositories on https://github.com/mate-desktop I see that many MATE components are released at version 1.26. And ArchLinux AUR says [the same](https://archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/mate/).

Is it possible to get this (or newer) version on my Ubuntu MATE 21.04 system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get latest MATE 1.26 on Ubuntu MATE 21.04 and even on 20.04 LTS running on PC (*amd64*) and Raspberry Pi (for both  *armhf* and *arm64*).

One should add the corresponding [Fresh MATE PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/fresh-mate) to the system by using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/fresh-mate
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and then reboot and enjoy:

[image: MATE 1.26 on Ubuntu MATE 21.04]

---

Note: you can always revert to previous MATE version by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/fresh-mate
```

You should do this before running release upgrade to Ubuntu MATE 21.10.

Note: if you need daily MATE build - use packages from [other PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mate-bot/+archive/ubuntu/daily-brew).

Comment: hi again @n0rbert 2 questions: (1) Any major changes or addition between `MATE 1.24.2` and `1.26`, and (2) Would this (upgrading MATE via PPA) create any issue when it's time to upgrade from `Ubuntu MATE 21.04` to `21.10`? Many thanks as always.

Comment: @Jags Upgrading to a new release always requires reverting to original state, that's what the package `ppa-purge` is made for.

Comment: @mook765 does that mean, just removing `PPAs` from `sources.list` or reverting packages back as listed in default Ubuntu repos too? Thank you.

Comment: @Jags It means to `sudo apt install ppa-purge` and then use `ppa-purge` to remove all ppa's and downgrade to original packages. You'd do that before you perform a release upgrade.

Comment: @mook765 okay, thanks alot.

Comment: [This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/fresh-mate/+packages) hosts newer (v1.26) and stable versions of packages (rather than daily packages of v1.25), and also, it is maintained by Martin Wimpress. It supports 20.04 too. I found about it in https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/08/install-mate-desktop-1-26-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, @ArchismanPanigrahi, of course I know. Edited answer to prioritize mentioned PPA over daily build.